# Communication between Vue.js components on separate pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components

I am beginner in Vue.js and I have a question related **to communication between Vue.js components which are not on the same page**.
I have multiple pages in my Vue.js app and I ***use router to navigate between them***. So I have ***“Home” page*** and ***“Search” page*** for filtering entities. 
 On “Home” page I also have less detailed search component and I wanted to use it just as a shortcut for “Search” page, so when user fills input fields and click on button, his search parameters are passed to the search component on “Search” page and "Search" page is displayed and then search is performed. Basically, I just want to **send data from that shortcut search component on “Home” page to search component on “Search” page**.
I tried using ***event bus*** and when button is clicked on “Home” page I emit parameters from "Home" page search:

```
methods:{
        searchApartments: function(){
            
            this.searchParameters.push(this.locationSearch);
            this.searchParameters.push(this.$refs.guestNumberInput.value);
            
            this.$root.$emit("searchApartmentsFromHomepage", this.searchParameters);        
            this.$root.$emit("showAppartmentPage");
        }
```

and on “Search” page search component I used **"mounted" lifecycle hook()** to listen to that event bus. Then I would **set fields**(which are bind to fields in "data" via "v-model") **on "Search" page component to values that I got from "Home" page**. Then, I would just call search function with these values:

```
    mounted(){
        this.$root.$on("searchApartmentsFromHomepage", (searchParameters) => {
            this.locationSearch = searchParameters[0];
            this.numberOfGuests = searchParameters[1];
            
            this.filterApartments();
        });
        
    },
```

I got everything to work, but input fields on "Search" page are not set to values that I have received from "Home" page. Unfortunately, even though values are passed successfully, they don't appear in fields of my search component and filter function doesn't get any data from them... 
 Does anyone has idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: it sounds like `Search` component instance hasn't been created when `Home` emits `searchApartment` event. And you stated `input fields on "Search" page are not set to values that I have received from "Home" page.`, how do you know `the values already received from "Home" page`?

Comment: @Sphinx That's what I thought, too. But I have limited Vue.js knowledge so I can't find  any different way to do it, except moving "Search" to the backend  and sending requests there... Do you have any advice or possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you emit event before `Search` page subscribed on it.

The easiest solution will be to params in redirect url.

As I understand currently you use redirection `/home` -> `/search`

And with search params it will be `/home` -> `/search?param=value&...`

Comment: Thanks for answer! I will try to do that, I just need to find how to add search parameters to URL and how to extract them in `Search` page...

Comment: From your comment it looks like you already use Vue Router.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html Here is examples of navigation between pages.

Comment: Yes, I do. I will try that now. Thanks for answer!